# Thumbnails do not open properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem of incompatibility of Internet Explorer on a page.
On this page there is a gallery with pictures (thumbnails) to be displayed. Each of these thumbnails have a link to an HTML page that displays the full size image:

http://www.crazzy.com.br/upload/upload-img/pictures/f53986b24d8eb7f398d521faa31a1bc9.jpg)

The problem is that in Internet Explorer these thumbnails are not being loaded correctly. If I clear the browser cache and try to enter the page, they appear normally.

However, upon entering the page again, the thumbnails do not appear.

http://www.crazzy.com.br/upload/upload-img/pictures/82c90a96a4710297e0d4c7ed99844956.jpg)

I tried to solve the problem by inserting a Meta not to cache but it still fails:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

The images are on a server from amazon and are usually coming. The problem is the same display.

In chrome, firefox and safari are appearing normally. I also tested on new versions of Internet Explorer and the problem persists.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Follows the code (For just a thumbnail). I removed the other to not be very extensive.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $(".img_thumb").each(function() {
                $(this).one('load', function() {
                    if($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
                        $(this).height(75);
                        $(this).width(52);
                    } else {
                        $(this).width(75);
                        $(this).height(52);
                    }
                    $(this).css("display", "inherit")
          });
            })
            })
        </script>

    <table width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" valign="middle">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td align="middle" valign="middle">
            <div id="titleframe">
               <div class="titleContent">
                  <div class="banner">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" border="0">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td valign="middle"></td>
                     <td valign="top">
                        <table>
                           <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                 <td align="middle">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                             <td valign="top" align="left"><a name="18864" href="Módulos/18864.html"><img class="img_thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/itatiaia/fotos/banheiros/serena/modulos/thumbnails/mod01.jpg" border="0" style="display:none; border:0pt solid white" alt=" "></a><br></td>
                                             <td valign="top" background="https://s3.amazonaws.com/itatiaia/fotos/bella/images/wh_rt.gif">
                                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/itatiaia/fotos/bella/images/wh_top_rt.gif"><br>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="auto" background="https://s3.amazonaws.com/itatiaia/fotos/bella/images/wh_bot.gif">
                                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/itatiaia/fotos/bella/images/wh_bot_lt.gif"><br>
                                             </td>
                                             <td valign="top">
                                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/itatiaia/fotos/bella/images/wh_bot_corner.gif"><br>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         <td valign="middle"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<div id="titleframe">
   <div class="titleContent">
      <div class="banner">
         <div class="info"></div>
         <div class="email"><a href="mailto:"></a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling issue here:

```
$(this).one('load', function() {

$(this).on('load', function() {
```

Also, use 1 handler for all events, not many handlers for a single class:

```
$(function(){
    $('.img_thumb').on('load', function() {
        if($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
            /* ... */
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok. But the problem continues

Answer (score 0):

The images might already be loaded before you add the load eventlistener for the same images. This is especially true if they got cached. (your meta tags wont help there, you're applying those to the html and it would also be unwanted)
One of several simple solutions could be to recreate the image element in your JavaScript and apply the EventListener on the shadow image.

There might be some errors here as I didn't test it nor did I write it in an editor:

```
$(".img_thumb").each(function() {
    var testImg = new Image(),
        orgImg = this,
        $orgImg = $(orgImg);
    testImg.load = function() {
        if($orgImg.height() > $orgImg.width()) {
            $orgImg.height(75);
            $orgImg.width(52);
        } else {
            $orgImg.width(75);
            $orgImg.height(52);
        }
        $orgImg.css("display", "inherit")
    }
    testImg.src = origImg.src;
});
```